# Why does adding to a singly linked list require O(1) constant time?

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

While doing leetcode, it says adding to a specific node in a singly linked list requires O(1) time complexity:

> Unlike an array, we don’t need to move all elements past the inserted element. Therefore, you can insert a new node into a linked list in O(1) time complexity, which is very efficient.

When deleting it's O(n) time which makes sense because you need to traverse to the node-1 and change the pointers. Isn't it the same when adding, which means it should also be O(n) time complexity?

Specifically, when adding, you still need to traverse to the index-1 you want to add at and change that node's `.next` to the new node.

[image]

Leetcode reference - adding: [here](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/linked-list/209/singly-linked-list/1288/) 
Leetcode reference - conclusion: [chart](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/linked-list/213/conclusion/1230/)

Comment: It is not clear what "given node" means. Do you have the index or do you have an actual node object!? Apparently it refers to the second but that is generally what happens in actual application, you never have access to the actual nodes.

Comment: @luk2302 Yeah I think your comment helps to clarify a lot for me. That it's just how they worded it, and if we assume you are given the actual node, then it's O(1) but if just given the index it's O(n). Edit: I reread the leetcode reference on adding and it does indeed say "GIVEN the prev node". So you're exactly right about interpreting the wording. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to know what the *given* input is. For instance, for the insert operation on a singly linked list you have highlighted the case where the node is given *after* which a new node should be inserted. This is indeed a O(1) operation. This is so because all the nodes that *precede* the given node are not affected by this operation.

This is different in this case: if for the delete operation the node is given that must be deleted, it cannot be done in O(1) in a singly linked list, because the node that **precedes** it must be updated. So now that preceding node must be retrieved by iterating from the start of the list.

We can "turn the tables":

What would be the time complexity if we were given a node and need to insert a new node **before** it? Then it will not be O(1), but O(n), for the simple reason that a change must be made to the node that **precedes** the given node.

What would be the time complexity if for a delete action we were given the node that precedes it? Then it can be done in O(1).

Still, if the input for either an insert or delete action is not a node reference, but an index, or a node's *value*, then both have a time complexity of O(n): the list must be traversed to find the given index or the given value.

So the time complexity for an action on a singly linked list depends very much on what the input is.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to traverse the list to insert an element *past* an existing, given element. For this, you only need to update the `next` pointers of the element you already have and of the element you are inserting. It's not necessary to know the previous element.

Note that even insertion past the last element can be implemented in O(1) on a singly-linked list, if you keep a reference to the last element of the list.

Comment: But under what circumstances do you have access to the node you want to insert after? In that case you can also reason that a deletion is O(1) if you have the element before the one you want to delete.

Comment: @luk2302 That's true. As the question is asked, it's about the theoretical possibility, not about it's real-live application. Many libraries won't give you access to the actual nodes of a linked list (for good reasons), but that doesn't mean that you can't write an implementation that does.